# Why is my C++ code not terminated when I sent SIGTERM (Ctrl + C) on Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, usb, fstream, ros

I wrote a program to read data from USB. The code goes like this:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "read_usb");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Rate loop_rate(100);
    while(ros::ok()){       
        std::string str;
        std::fstream openmv_cam_h7;
        openmv_cam_h7.open("/dev/ttyACM0");     
        while(openmv_cam_h7 >> str){
            std::cout << str << std::endl;
        }
        openmv_cam_h7.close();
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
}
```

When I ran the program, it went well. But when I want to terminate it by pressing Ctrl+C (SIGTERM) on Ubuntu Terminal, the program kept running. It terminated only when I unplugged the USB device that was used to send the data.

Why does this happen? What should I do if I want the program to terminate when I send the SIGTERM signal?

Additional Info:
My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and I use ROS Melodic.

Comment: Did you try using Ctrl^Z instead? It usually works...

Comment: Yeah, it worked. I killed the process by using 'kill -9'.

Comment: Good. Just a heads up. you can restart the process with `fg` and put it as a background job using `bg` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually pressing Ctrl+C will kill your program without any issues.

Below are my suspicions & solutions:

1. Ubuntu may be having issues and not sending the SIGTERM to your application. To test if Ubuntu is working correctly, create an empty program with ONE while(true) {} loop, (just block forever) and test if you can CTRL+C this program. If it exits, then its your code that has a problem.
2. If point 1 worked, then I feel the loop_rate.sleep() or ros::spinOnce() may be somehow causing issues with catching the SIGTERM. sleep or spinOnce could be locking up the application for small peroids of time (who knows). Try removing them and retest CTRL+C. Also, try to smash the CTRL+C a bunch of times(quickly) and see if this triggers an exit. If this does work, then you will need to figure out why ROS / sleep() or spinOnce() methods are locking up your application (intermittently), and therefore not catching the SIGTERM.
3. ROS may have hooked the SIGTERM handler itself in the library and may be doing something with it(not exiting obviously). If this is the case, you may have to add your own SIGTERM handler in your main, so you will catch the CTRL+C, and then call exit() manually.

Give these a try and get back to us.

Comment: Your suggestion, especially point 1, gave me an idea to check the loops in my code. Yes, it turned out that my code stucked at while(openmv_cam_h7 >> str). Now, I have written new code that worked. Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear! Loops blocking or lagging is quite the common problem, and can cause all sorts of interesting symptoms. Glad it helped.